# form:errors does not display error message when value is rejected

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc, forms

the complete code is in github:
https://github.com/cuipengfei/MPJSP/tree/master/tmp

in the controller, there is a method that handles the submit:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void handleSubmit(Customer model, BindingResult result) {
        System.out.println(model.getUserName());
        result.rejectValue("userName", "required.userName", "user name invalid");
    }
```

and in jsp, there is a form like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="home" modelAttribute="Customer">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username :</td>
            <td><form:input path="userName" /></td>
            <td><form:errors path="userName" cssClass="error" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>
```

the controllers just rejects value every time, but the error message is not displayed.

the complete code can be found here:
https://github.com/cuipengfei/MPJSP/tree/master/tmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to set commandName attribute in your form tag

```
<form:form method="POST" action="home" commandName="Customer">
```

Comment: Do you see your output System.out.println(model.getUserName());?

Comment: try to make your method return value as String ad return "/home" from handleSubmit()